# Add an Android annotation to a param of List<T> for type-hinting

Tags: android, android-annotations

Normally, if we have a int parameter `id` to present a resource ID in Android. we could add annotations like `@StringRes` or `@DrawableRes` from `androidx.annotation`. So that IDE could use the information to check type for us, which is nice.

Now, I have a method that signature looks like the snippet below. The type of the param `ids` is `List<Int>`. The element in the list should be one of the drawable ids, for example, `R.drawable.background`. But I don't know how to let IDE remind me or people who use this function shortly.

```
/**
 * @param ids the collection of drawable resources as candidates to be selected.
 */
fun ImageSelector(initialIndex: Int, ids: List<Int>, onSelected: (Int) -> Unit) {}
```

I have tried `ids: List<@DrawableRes Int>`, which did not working.

I write doc comments for the method for now. I am still wondering the way to achieve this, Although annotation is just a nice-to-have feature.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a current way to do this, or are you asking how you would do this if you wanted to implement it yourself?

Comment: I am asking a way without custom implementation.

Comment: Too bad, I'd find that an interesting problem to help out on.  But in order for this to work, you'd need to be able to not just annotate the variable, but you'd need to know which functions on the variable also must take a variable that's typed like that.  Which might be able to be done if there was an annotation on the type (maybe), but DrawbleRes can't be put on a type.

Comment: After many tries, My conclusion is more like yours. So in other ways, Is there any annotation for the collection likes List or Map? So it could takes parameter for the generic type?

Comment: Not that I know of.   I do think it could be done though.  Create a Type annotation for the type param-  DrawableResType.  Have an annotation processor walk from the type to the enclosing class.  Loop over all the elements of the class, finding all functions and constructors.  On each of those, walk all the parameters and check if they're a generic of that type.  Then for each of those, treat it as if that parameter has DrawableRes annotated to it (whatever that does in the annotation processor that handles drawable res). So its doable, just nobody to my knowledge has done it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I have in place at the moment is a wrapping data class like this:

`data class StringResource(@StringRes val id: Int)`

I use that in my parameterized types in place of an `Int`, and everything seems happy. I get a warning if I try to do something like `StringResource(123456)` instead of `StringResource(R.string.blah_blah)`.